# Why the votes to close on a perfectly legitimate question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

[How can I get a list of tables in a SQL Server database along with the primary key using ONLY C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548852/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-tables-in-a-sql-server-database-along-with-the-primary-ke)

Why did two people vote to close on a legitimate question? It seems they were annoyed that their answers were deemed worthless and obviously not the answer to what I was asking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3548852/revisions) of that question was indeed a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175415/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-tables-in-a-database-using-tsql).

Once you clarified you needed something else, people stopped voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

The two close votes are 'Close As Duplicate' and point to the TSQL post they mentioned in the comments.  In fact, the first comment was made automatically when the first vote was cast.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, some users thought it was a duplicate as indicated in the revisions.

Secondly, it hasn't been closed yet. So don't worry about it. If you think you had been unfairly targeted you could always flag it for moderator investigation and if you were being unfairly targeted and the question was reasonable then there is a good change it would be reopened.

As it stands, don't worry about it unless it gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

At least one person thought it was a duplicate of another question and voted to close as such, as evidenced by the automatically generated comment.